# shell script which will interact with the database

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, sqlplus

Have been writing the shell script such as :

```
#! /bin/bash
`sqlplus -s <username>/<passwd>@dbname`    
set echo on  
set pagesize 0  
set verify off  
set lines 32000  
set trimspool on  
set feedback off  
`SELECT tr.number, count(*) as total  
              FROM <dbname>.<tablename1> tr  
              LEFT JOIN <tablename2> t2 ON t2.id2 = tr.id1  
              LEFT JOIN <tablename3> t3 ON t3.id2 = tr.id1  
              LEFT JOIN <tablename4> t4 ON t4.id2 = tr.id1  
              WHERE tr.TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE - 75 / 1440  
               AND tr.TIMESTAMP <= SYSDATE - 15 / 1440  
              and (t2.number like '2____' OR t2.number like '3____' OR t2.number like '99____' )  
AND tr.id = 703 and t2.v1 = 100  
          group by (tr.number);`  
exit;  
EOF
```

Currently my output is like ::

```
 tr.number                    count(*)  
 27684                        76        
 27050                         9        
 37744                         7        
 997717                       11        
 997797                        8        
 37224                         3
```

I want to group the count of numbers 2_***, 3*__**, 99_*_*  such as

```
tr.number  count(*)  
 2____      76+9  
 3____      7+3  
 99_____    11+8
```

the output should be ONLY in 3 rows with starting digits as 2,3 and 99 in three rows as shown above.

`_` represents 4 places.

Please advise.

P.S. Could you please advise why is it essential to put SET operators and their brief description.

Thanks !

Comment: Not sureI understand what you mean by this "P.S. Could you please advise why is it essential to put SET operators and their brief description". Is this related to the above question?

Comment: Not sure the shell script is relevant either really; the question seems to be all about the `select`

Comment: Hello Alex, yes, the query is related to SELECT only but i'll be posting more additional queries at this post related to my shell script, so therefore i put it here :-)

Comment: If they are different queries then you should post separate questions; clarifying an existing question is fine but if you ask something new then few people will see it if the original has already been answered, and each question should only have the appropriate tags - this one shouldn't really have `bash`. Just for the heck of it though, I don't think your script will run, though that might be transcription errors; you shouldn't have any back-ticks, and the first line should be `sqlplus -s <username>/<passwd>@dbname <<EOF`

Comment: Okay, Sure, will post it separately, thanks :-) Also, have note down your inputs as well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first one or two characters of tr.number and then group on it to get the expected results.

Since you haven't provided the table creation scripts, I've created a demo table and its data to illustrate the point.

```
create table tr(
   id number,
   total_records number);

insert into tr values (200123,50);
insert into tr values (20034, 25);
insert into tr values (30034, 15);
insert into tr values (300567, 100);
insert into tr values (990034, 75);
insert into tr values (990034, 80);
insert into tr values (990034, 456);
commit;


SELECT   starts_with, SUM (total_records) total_records
    FROM (SELECT ID,
                 (CASE WHEN ID LIKE '2%'  THEN '2____'
                       WHEN ID LIKE '3%'  THEN '3____'
                       WHEN ID LIKE '99%' THEN '99____'
                  END
                 ) starts_with,
                 total_records
            FROM tr
            where ( id like '2%' or id like '3%' or id like '99%'))
GROUP BY starts_with;

STARTS TOTAL_RECORDS
------ -------------
2____             75
3____            115
99____           611
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me :-) Now i have sthin more to ask soon on the same.

Comment: Now, i have to send the output via email to a particular email-address from script if the total_records gets equal to 0. That email should have subject and body as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can see what the SET commands do in the manual: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rajesh,

Now, i have to send the output via email to a particular email-address from script if the total_records gets equal to 0. That email should have subject and body as well.

Comment: this should be a new question as it is a different topic.